# Given a any String. Enter any character from the keyboard, printing the number of characters this word appears in the given string

Tags: string, rust, count

### I tried `find()`, but it returns the position of the first character
This is my code

File: Main.rs

```
use std::fs;
fn main() {
    let mut data = fs::read_to_string("./Text").expect("Unable to read file");
    let g_index = data.find("g");   // 3
    println!("{:?}",g_index)
}
```

---

File: Text (https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0960982203005347-mmc6.txt)

Comment: confusing title, still not clear on problem

Answer (score 1):

You can get an iterator over the characters of a string via [`chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars), then use standard iterator methods [`filter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) and [`count()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count):

```rust
s.chars().filter(|&c| c == 'g').count();
```

Comment: What do we put in some_char

Comment: @PhanHoàngLong The character you want to find.